# How to set timeout in Spring WebServiceTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I am using [`org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) for making Web Service calls. How can i configure timeout for the call.

Answer (score 53):

If you are using Spring Webservices 2.1.0 version, You can set timeout using [HttpComponentsMessageSender](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpComponentsMessageSender.html).

[CommonsHttpMessageSender](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/CommonsHttpMessageSender.html) are deprecated and not recommended by Spring anymore.

The way I have it implemented, I define my WebServiceTemplate to use HttpComponentsMessageSender.

Values are in Milliseconds

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="${endpoint.url}" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1200000" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="1200000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Just Make sure you have in your pom file, you added the following

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 14):

Same as Sathish answer, but programmatically (Spring 4+):

```
@Component
public class MyWebServiceGatewaySupport extends WebServiceGatewaySupport
{
    @Value("${my.ws.readtimeout}")
    private String readTimeout;

    @Value("${my.ws.connectiontimeout}")
    private String connectionTimeout;

    Object marshalSendAndReceive(String endpoint, Object requestPayload)
    {

        WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = this.getWebServiceTemplate();
        WebServiceMessageSender[] senders = wsTemplate.getMessageSenders();
        for (WebServiceMessageSender sender: senders)
        {
            try
            {
                int readTimeoutMsec = Integer.parseInt(readTimeout);
                int connTimeoutMsec = Integer.parseInt(connectionTimeout);
                HttpComponentsMessageSender httpSender = (HttpComponentsMessageSender) sender;
                httpSender.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutMsec);
                httpSender.setConnectionTimeout(connTimeoutMsec);
            }
            catch (ClassCastException|NumberFormatException cex)
            {
                 logger.warn("Cannot set WS timeout: " + cex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(endpoint, requestPayload);

     }
 }
```

Comment: I am using in my project of Spring Boot and Spring WS an injection using `Integer` already, e.g. `@Value("${my.ws.readtimeout}") private Integer readTimeout`

Comment: I had to find `HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender` within `senders` and provide `java.time.Duration.ofMillis()` to the setters instead.

Comment: Getting error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:211)
 at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(HttpComponentsMessageSender.java:149)

Answer (score 12):

Since Spring Webservices 2.2, you can also use Spring's [ClientHttpRequestMessageSender](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws/2.2.0.RC1/spring-ws-2.2.0.RC1-docs.zip!/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/ClientHttpRequestMessageSender.html):

```
@Service
public class CustomWebServiceImpl extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements CustomWebService {
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = (10 * 1000);
    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = (10 * 1000);

    public CustomWebServiceImpl() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        setMessageSender(new ClientHttpRequestMessageSender(requestFactory));
    }

    (...)
}
```

(no dependency to Apache HTTP Components required)

Comment: Thank you @darrachequesne, this solved my issue :)

Answer (score 10):

The below code worked for me.

```
@Bean
public YourClassImpl yourClassImpl(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller, HttpComponentsMessageSender  httpComponentsMessageSender) {
    YourClassImpl client = new YourClassImpl();
    client.setDefaultUri(PiiProperties.SOAP_ACTION.getValue());
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender);
    return client;
}

@Bean
public HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender() {     
    HttpComponentsMessageSender sender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
    sender.setReadTimeout(1000);
    sender.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
    return sender;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want that kind of control, you can

- either [switch to CommonsHttpMessageSender, which uses the Jakarta Commons
  HttpClient](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/client.html#client-transports)
- or subclass [`HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender.html) and in the
  [`prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender.html#prepareConnection%28java.net.HttpURLConnection%29) method call
  [`UrlConnection.setReadTimeOut(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: So, there is not even a default timeout for WebServiceTemplate ? how long can the call be valid ?

Comment: Is it possible to set the timeout per request? This way we could adjust the timeout in runtime.

Answer (score 5):

That's how I did:

```
@Configuration
public class MunisServiceConfig {

    @Value("${service.uri}")
    private String soapUri;

    @Bean
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(CheckStatePayment.class.getPackage().getName());

        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate munisService() {
        WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();

        template.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        template.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());

        template.setDefaultUri(soapUri);

        HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(3000);
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        template.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender);

        return template;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This article will probably sort you out:
http://onebyteatatime.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/how-to-set-socket-timeout-using-spring-webservicetemplate/

The way I have it implemented, I define my WebServiceTemplate to use CommonsHttpMessageSender:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Then, in code, I get the messageSender and set the timeout on it. You could equally do this in your xml.

```
CommonsHttpMessageSender messageSender = (CommonsHttpMessageSender)webServiceTemplate.getMessageSenders()[0];
messageSender.getHttpClient().getParams().setSoTimeout(timeoutMillis);
```

Answer (score 4):

This code works with **Spring Boot** (verified on 2.1.5.RELEASE):

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleServiceClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${example-service.uri}")
    private String exampleServiceUri;

    @Value("${example-service.timeout:120}")
    private int exampleServiceTimeout;

    @Bean
    public ExampleServiceClient exampleServiceClient() {
        ExampleServiceClient client = new ExampleServiceClient();
        client.setMessageSender(httpUrlConnectionMessageSender());
        client.setDefaultUri(exampleServiceUri);
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender httpUrlConnectionMessageSender() {
        HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(exampleServiceTimeout);
        sender.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        sender.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
        return sender;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath(ObjectFactory.class.getPackageName());
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Comment: something like this also works for Spring Boot

```java
var messageSender = new HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder().setReadTimeout(properties.getHttpReadTimeout()).setConnectTimeout(properties.getHttpConnectTimeout()).build();

return builder.setMarshaller(marshaller) .setUnmarshaller(marshaller).additionalMessageSenders(messageSender).build();
```

builder is from `WebServiceTemplateBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

For the CommonsHttpMessageSender, we can set the timeout in the following way:

```
<bean id="httpParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
  <!-- Timeout in milliseconds: in this case 1 minute -->
  <property name="soTimeout" value="60000" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <property name="params" ref="httpParams" />
</bean>

<!-- Define the message sender used by all web service templates -->
<bean id="webServiceMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="httpClient"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and ref the webServiceMessageSender as below:

```
<bean id="genericWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
       <property name="messageSender" ref="webServiceMessageSender"/>
</bean>
```