# Spring SOAP Webservice Consumer/Client example using apache HttpClient5

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, java-17

Spring SOAP Webservice Consumer/Client example using apache HttpClient5

Spring SOAP Webservice is still using HttpClient implementation, HttpClient 4.x. When I open the Spring WS API for `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender` to set ConnectionTimeout, it still uses HttpClient 4.x java classes.

But I am looking for Spring SOAP WebService using apache HttpClient5 component classes.

Can someone help here to provide the equivalent example.

Please dont give me old examples.

I am using Java 17, SpringBoot 3.0.1, Spring-ws-core 4.0.0

I referred internet, here are some of the below URLs

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/migration-guide/index.html

https://snehapatil02.medium.com/soap-web-service-client-with-spring-boot-3c7034351c46

[How to set timeout in Spring WebServiceTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733744/how-to-set-timeout-in-spring-webservicetemplate)

Answer (score 1):

It is still in the works.

If you really want to use it you can always use the [`ClientHttpRequestMessageSender`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/ClientHttpRequestMessageSender.html), which uses the Spring Framework `ClientHttpRequest` abstraction, which does support Apache Http Client5.

Comment: Could you provide any example URL?

Comment: It isn't any different as configuring another `MessageSender` but you have an additional layer of abstraction. That shouldn't be that hard to configure.